# How to remove '\u{ef}' character from String Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode-string

let's say I have a string

```
var a = "#bb #cccc #ddddd\u{ef}"
```

and i am setting it to textview like this

```
let text = a.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
let textRemoved = text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
textView.text = textRemove
```

I am trying to remove the `\u{ef}` character here. But in `textRemoved` it is not happening. Please help me how to do it.

> I am using Xcode 10. Looks like below Xcode version than 10 is working
>   fine. is it a bug of Xcode 10?

Comment: So does the text contain the 6 characters `\u{ef}`, or the code point U+00EF LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS?

Comment: This code works correctly in playground

Comment: Try doing `text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\u{ef}"...` with double backslash.

Comment: The code is working fine is Playground

Comment: for char in strMainString.unicodeScalars{
            if char.isASCII{
                newNumber += String(char)
            }
        }

Comment: Check [this thread of Apple's dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/272312). Do you think it is related to your issue?

Comment: @OOPer I think my issue is related to the one you mentioned

Comment: @JasonBourne, the thread I have shown tells us two thing: -- Do not rely on the outputs in the debug area of Xcode. -- The extra character you need remove may not be `\{ef}`. Try removing `\u{FFFC}` instead, or check what is the actual extra character by putting `print(text.data(using: .utf8) as! NSData)`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a late answer but I struggled to replace "\u{ef}" in string as well. During debugging when hovered over string it showed presence of \u{ef} but when print in description it only showed space.

```
let str = "\u{ef} Some Title"
print(str) //" Some Title"
```

I tried `replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` but it failed as well.

So I used below snippet and it worked like wonder.

```
 let modifiedStr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
print(modifiedStr)  //"Some Title"
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same issue for **"\u{e2}"**. i have searched a lot but unable to find any answer. then i have tried below code , which works for me.

```
var newString = ""
for char in strMainString.unicodeScalars{
    if char.isASCII{
        newString += String(char)
    }
}
```

Hope that will also work for you too.

Comment: This solution returned empty string in every case in arabic search it will not only remove \u{e2}"

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 10 Playground, string replaces for `\u{00EF}` is working.

```
var a = "#bb #cccc #ddddd\u{ef}" 
a = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00EF}", with: "")
```

I hope that will work for you.

Comment: its not working. trying to get a text from textview.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked like a charm:

```
replacingOccurrences(of: "�", with: " ", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g. 1

```
let text = "\u{ef}\u{ef}\u{ef}\u{ef}哦哦哦"
        
let text1 = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)

let text2 = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

[runnable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/styVo.png)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/styVo.png"/>
```

e.g. 2

```
let strBefore = textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput 
let strAfter  = textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput 
var textInput = strBefore + strAfter

let textInput2 = textInput.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
        
let textInput1 = textInput.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

[runnable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGHtW.png)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGHtW.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to question but with `\u{e2}` symbol (fix is the same):

`\u{e2}` is not a character rather subset of UTF8 plane which starts with `0xE2` byte.

So look [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128), E2 are general punctuation symbols.
There many symbols actually which started with `\u{e2}` but not limited to it and full char can be represented f.e. with `e2 80 a8` bytes   (line separator).

That explains why shown in Xcode `\u{e2}` can't be replaced with `replacingOccurrences`... function. In order to filter out correct symbol you have to know what exact symbol it is, f.e. by using the snippet below:

```
"\u{2028}&".forEach { (char) in
   print(Data(char.utf8).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined(separator: " "))
 }
```

it prints to console:

```
e2 80 a8
26
f0 9f 98 b2
```

which are byte representation for each symbol.

Next step is to filter your string, go [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128) and search in 3d column your bytes and unicode code point value is what you need (first column) and write it in swift code like `"\u{2028}\u{206A}..."` (depending on your sorting).

The final function may look like:

```
func removingE2Symbols() -> String {
    let specialChars = "\u{202A}\u{202C}"
    return filter { !specialChars.contains($0) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
extension String {
    var asciiString: String {
        return String(self.unicodeScalars.filter{ $0.isASCII })
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It,s working Please check again:

```
 let a = "#bb #cccc #ddddd\u{ef}"
 let text = a.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
 let textRemoved = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{ef}", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
 print(textRemoved)
```

[image]

Comment: it might possible that it is not working , as it is special character. I also faced same issue for "\\u{e2}"

Comment: I can not figure out what is wrong with my thought process, I tried everything but can not eliminate the unicode character when i am trying to get text from the textfield  :(